# adding images to html and css

Tags: html, css

i cant figure out how to add a background image or an image with text over it. i feel im supposed to do something with floating or positioning but i cant figure it out. my html and css are a hot mess cause im a newbie. i have been trying to add an image to the background1 class. and then add an h2 header over it. any ideas? my dom may be messed up cause im still alittle hazy about understanding parent child elements etc. any tips or advice or things to check?

```css
/* top navigation */

body {
 margin:0;
}

.iconsnav {
 height: 37px;
 width:92%;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 1.1em;
 padding-left: 8%;
 background-color: #171717;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

span {
 color:#3399dd;
 margin:0.7%;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}

.icon-facebook {
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.icon-twitter {
 margin: 0%
}

.icon-envelop {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 2em;
}

span:hover {
 color:#9af1cc;
}


/* header */

.header {
 height: 95px;
 background-color: #242424;
 padding-right: 13em;
}

.whitelogo {
 margin-top: 1.1em;
 margin-left: 5.5em;
 height: 70%;
 width: auto;
}

.contoctbuttontop {
 margin: 0%
}

.upperlinks {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
 color: #919191;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 3.5em;
 margin-top: 3em;
}

a:hover {
 color: #f4f4f4;
}

/* background section 1 */

.background1 {
 height: 70em;
 width:100;
 background-image: url('girlfc.png');
}


.background1 img {
 height: 5em;
 width:auto;
}


h2 {
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 0.4em;
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 4em;

}

/* footer */

.footer {
 height: 4.5em;
 width: 94%;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 1.1em;
 padding-left: 5.8%;
 background-color: #ededed;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

.blacklogo {
 height: 30px;
}

p {
 color: #919191;
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.65em;

}
```

```html
<title>AZ Kinetic Fitness</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="AKFmain.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/293e1b58d5/UntitledProject2/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,400|Roboto:400,100|Raleway:400,200|Titillium+Web:400,200|Exo+2:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <div class="iconsnav">
   <nav>
    <span class="icon-twitter"></span>
    <span class="icon-facebook"></span>
    <span class="icon-youtube3"></span>
    <span class="icon-instagram"></span>
    <span class="icon-envelop"></span>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="header">
  <img src="azkineticfitnesswhitelogooutline.png" class="whitelogo"/>
  <a href="www" class="upperlinks">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="www" class="upperlinks">STUDIO LOCATIONS</a>
  <a href="www" class="upperlinks">PROGRAMS</a>
  <a href="www" class="upperlinks">HOME</a>
 </div>
 <div class="background1">
  <img src="girlfc.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
  <img src="azkineticfitblacklogo.png" class="blacklogo"/>
  <p>&copy;2015 Arizona Kinetic Fitness. All Rights Reserved.</p>
 </div>


</body>





</html>
```

Comment: Where is your `<h2>` element?? This is what we can see currently from your code. http://jsbin.com/gucizi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

To set a child over parent use positioning like this
and your `background-image:url('yourImage.png');`
is ok.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        yuor text here...
    </div>
</div>

.parent{
position:relative;
}
child{
position:absolute;
left:20%;
top:20%;
}
```

[background-image is ok](http://jsfiddle.net/o23z9b7n/)